# How to run two parallel gnome-terminal windows?

Tags: shell, shell-script, gnome-terminal

I'm looking to run two independent parallel gnome-terminal windows with some parameters, from one shell script.

So far I've got this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -e window1.sh &
gnome-terminal -e window2.sh &
exit
```

However, upon running this, the screens flash up and disappear. I was expecting both to appear, wait for key input, then continue working as normal terminal windows would, i.e., I should be able to continue typing commands into them both.

Here's the code for window1.sh + window2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo window 
read -p "press any key to continue"
```

I don't understand why they aren't even respecting the 'read' and waiting for input.

Comment: I tested with `konsole` I added `--noclose` option. I get this output `window\n
press any key to continue/home/richard/trash/term-test: 3: read: arg count`

Comment: Run unit tests. If you had tested `window1.sh` on its own, then you would realise that it is this script that is at fault.

Comment: Hi Richard, I've done exactly that and window1.sh works just fine. I don't get the same output as you. I literally just get 'press any key to continue'. I don't get all the extra stuff.

Comment: What then happens when you press a key?

Comment: I just return back to the terminal, from the place I ran the script

Comment: Note using a file extension on scripts in non-Unix: it stops polymorphism. That is, it makes the caller dependant on the implementation e.g. if you change the implementation, to python, or C, then would you change the file extension. If so you have to change every program that uses your program/script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script on its own.

`./window1.sh`

You will get this output.

```
window
press any key to continue./window1.sh: 3: read: arg count
```

This is because `read` is a `bash` command, but not a `sh` command.

Comment: Hey Richard, 

Thanks for your time.

I don't get the same output as you.

I only get "window" followed by "press any key to continue" - I don't get the 'term-test' bit

Comment: @user1203297: Is `/bin/sh` bash or dash on your system?  Probably bash on yours, dash on Richard's.

Comment: It's bash on mine

Comment: My `sh` is `dash` I changed `window1.sh` to use `bash` then, ran `konsole -e window1.sh`. It worked good. I got a window it displayed the 2 lines of text I pressed `Enter` (the only key), and the window closed.

Comment: Could you try with gnome-terminal please?

Comment: @user1203297: test your terminal with `gnome-terminal -e cat`.  If it runs `cat` to echo back anything you type, then you know that part worked, and that it's your script that's the problem.

Comment: Okay, I've rebooted the machine and magically it works...sigh. I have no idea why this makes a difference. Apologies for wasting your time.

However in regard to making the two new windows now 'dynamic' - so after I press enter I want to be able to use them as normal terminal windows. How would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: There is a way to get bash to run a script as initialisation, then prompt. Can't remember the option. But that is another question.

Comment: Found it, just run 'exec bash' - for future reference.

Comment: `read` is actually a POSIX `sh` command. However, the `-p` option is a Bash extension: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

Answer (score 1):

Are the scripts executable and in your `$PATH`?  You probably need

```
gnome-terminal -e ./window1.sh &
```

Also, if the scripts are similar, write it once and pass a parameter as an argument:

```
gnome-terminal -e ./window.sh 1 &
gnome-terminal -e ./window.sh 2 &
```

`"$@"` expands to the command line args, each quoted separately.  `"$1"` is the first arg, etc. etc.

Comment: It this scenario using `konsole --noclose` I get a nice error: `Warning: Could not find '/home/richard/…/window1.sh'', starting '/bin/bash' instead.  Please check your profile settings.`

Comment: Thanks Peter.
The scripts are similar for this POC - but I'm going to be expanding them into very different scripts at a later date with different names. So unfortunately I can't pass the numbers as a parameter.

I've tried to use absolute paths too - but it hasn't helped.